# Writing to a comet stream using tomcat 6.0

Tags: java, comet, tomcat6

Hey I'm new to java servlets and I am trying to write one that uses comet so that I can create a long polling Ajax request. I can successfully start the stream and perform operations but I can't write anything out. Here is my code:

```
 public class CometTestServlet extends HttpServlet implements CometProcessor { 
      /**
     * 
     */
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1070949541963627977L;
    private MessageSender messageSender = null;
    protected ArrayList<HttpServletResponse> connections = new ArrayList<HttpServletResponse>();

    public void event(CometEvent cometEvent) throws IOException, ServletException { 
        HttpServletRequest request = cometEvent.getHttpServletRequest();
        HttpServletResponse response = cometEvent.getHttpServletResponse();
        //final PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();
        if (cometEvent.getEventType() == CometEvent.EventType.BEGIN) {
            PrintWriter writer = response.getWriter();
            writer.println("<!doctype html public \"-//w3c//dtd html 4.0 transitional//en\">");
            writer.println("<head><title>JSP Chat</title></head><body bgcolor=\"#FFFFFF\">");
writer.println("</body></html>");
            writer.flush();
            cometEvent.setTimeout(10 * 1000);
            //cometEvent.close();
        } else if (cometEvent.getEventType() == CometEvent.EventType.ERROR) { 
            log("Error for session: " + request.getSession(true).getId());
            synchronized(connections) {
                connections.remove(response);
            }
            cometEvent.close(); 
        } else if (cometEvent.getEventType() == CometEvent.EventType.END) { 
            log("End for session: " + request.getSession(true).getId());
            synchronized(connections) {
                connections.remove(response);
            }
            PrintWriter writer = response.getWriter();
            writer.println("</body></html>");
            cometEvent.close();
        } else if (cometEvent.getEventType() == CometEvent.EventType.READ) { 
            //handleReadEvent(cometEvent);
            InputStream is = request.getInputStream();
            byte[] buf = new byte[512];
            do {
                int n = is.read(buf); //can throw an IOException
                if (n > 0) {
                    log("Read " + n + " bytes: " + new String(buf, 0, n) 
                            + " for session: " + request.getSession(true).getId());
                } else if (n < 0) {
                    //error(cometEvent, request, response);
                    return;
                }
            } while (is.available() > 0);
        }
    }
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: One problem I see, is that you never add your connection to the list, like: `if (cometEvent.getEventType() == CometEvent.EventType.BEGIN) { ... synchronized(connections) {connections.add(response);}}` But that's probably not the solution.

Comment: Oh thats true I don't. Thats not the problems but thanks for the catch.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're new to servlets and trying to run Comet code on Tomcat, a good start is to run the example code from http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-6.0-doc/aio.html.

Very very important (from that page) is "*IMPORTANT NOTE: Usage of these features requires using the APR or NIO HTTP connectors. The classic java.io HTTP connector and the AJP connectors do not support them.*"

**If you don't configure your Tomcat instance to use NIO instead of the plain HTTP connector, Comet will not work.**

Comment: I changed my connection protocal in the server.xml file to this:       
 <Connector connectionTimeout="20000" port="8080"
        protocol="org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11NioProtocol"
        redirectPort="8443" />
Is that what you mean? because if it is then it doesn't help.

Comment: It helps, but this also means you have other problems in your code.  Does the sample code work for you?